# Garbage collection log for groovy?

Tags: groovy, garbage-collection

I'm the inheritor of a groovy application. The groovy part is rather small, maybe 500 loc that's mostly used to prime and start java threads.
Now the sys admin people comes to me with tales of woe, with tales of the dreaded OOME.
With a java app I would take a look at the gc log but here there is none such.
How do I get a gc log for groovy? Is it possible?

I've googled around for quite a bit to no avail. 
Anybody with any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With a java app I would take a look at the gc log but here there is none such.

groovy runs on the JVM, it accepts the same JVM options as java applications would. You can pass them via the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable